# Running Time of built in functions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

if I use built in functions from java do I have to take into consideration there running time or should I count them as constant time. what will be the time complexity of the following function

```
def int findMax(int [] a)
    {
    a.Arrays.sort();
    n=a.length;
    return a[n-1];
    }
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Boann He says "built-in functions from Java," so I'm assuming Java. He should clarify, though.

Comment: @furkle Well it's clearly not Java code.

Comment: @Boann Also true. I guess the question is, do they *imagine* it to be Java code?

Comment: Of course the build-in functions of a language should NOT be considered as constant-time. Their complexity depends on the algorithm they implement, so yes you must take them into account too

Comment: assuming it to be java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all the work here is being done by the sort() algorithm. For sorting arrays, Java uses Quicksort, which has an O(n log n) average and O(n^2) worst case performance.

From the Java documentation on sort():

> Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

Given your question lacks any use case whatsoever, and your comment on my answer, I feel like I have to point out that this is a classic example of premature optimization. You're looking for the mathematical complexity of a trivial method without any indication that this method will account for any significant portion of the CPU-time used by your program. This is especially true given that your implementation is incredibly inefficient: iterating through the array and storing the highest value would execute in O(n).

Comment: so my runtime will be O(nlogn)?

Comment: @jeetTAKWANI Your runtime for *this specific method*, in average cases, will be O(n log n). Which is almost entirely useless as a metric for a method that lacks an greater context from which to judge it.

Comment: @jeetTAKWANI,  yes, if you first sort it, it will be `O(n*log(n))` on average.   However, finding the max value can easily be done in `O(n)`, of course: just scan the array and keep track of the largest value.

Comment: @jeetTAKWANI If this has answered your question, please select the answer with the check mark.